# How to store files in the web that can be accessible from Android App?

Tags: android

I need to store some audio files in the web that can be downloaded to the Android App through an URL. How can i store these files for free? Will Google Drive help?

Answer (score 2):

If you want direct downloads to files then you'll probably want to host the files on a web host. You can use Amazon's S3 (free) for example. This way you'll have direct links to those files.

Comment: Thanks for answering... i read about Amazon s3... it is free only for a year.. is there any other option?